# Why do some questions never get marked as a duplicate, but others do?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today I saw that a question was marked as a duplicate, but the original was also a duplicate. The question marked as a duplicate can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957860/detect-user-scroll-down-or-scroll-up-in-jquery). The question that is a duplicate, but never got marked as one can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989632/differentiate-between-scroll-up-down-in-jquery). The real original question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event).

So why did the first question get marked as a duplicate, but the second one didn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, because nobody flagged the question as a duplicate, or cast a close vote. You can see this in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4989632/timeline) of the post - both actions would have put this in the Close Vote review queue, of which there would be a trace in the timeline. Note that the [Close Vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) is by far the largest queue, so it might not even be reviewed completely before the votes age away.

Comment: So it probably won't ever get marked as a duplicate then?

Comment: @JacquesMarais you can initiate this yourself, by clicking the 'flag' option below the question.

Comment: I have done so already.

Comment: @JacquesMarais thanks - it worked, it is now in the review queue: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hmfDC.png

Comment: Ok, thanks. Hope it will get fixed soon

Answer (score 8):

Questions will only be closed as a duplicate if:

1) Somebody notices that it is a duplicate
2) Bothers to flag it as such
3) The flag is seen and acted upon before it ages away

It is often the first point - the noticing - that doesn't happen.
Now you've noticed a duplicate, you've achieved the first step.  Flag it.

There are probably hundreds of duplicate questions across the SE sites.